# How to manage huge sized classes and refactoring in unit testing (junit)

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, automated-tests

In our project which has huge sized classes and sub relations we have been developing for months. Also, we have been developing junit test cases.

Automatic unit tests are good in general, but in real life it is not easy as we think. Managing the unit test architecture is easier than creating mock objects and stubs etc. Also, we are testing the dao and service layers.

**The problem** is that our classes have so many attributes. (I know it's not a good object oriendted design but it's legacy architecture.)

For example; customer class has **58 attributes** and it's related to address, marsaccounts and etc. Totally if you want to test this class you have to create inputs, inputs with **90 or more attributes.**

Our architecture has many  business rule on Customer, so that we have to create more than **50** customer inputs to test every rule, method or flow.

In short, you have to create **4500 (90 x 50)** attributes for all, but less for a reliable test (only necessary attributes).

Preparing the test inputs are painful and annoying. **Imagine, 2 columns added** to Customer object and they store critical values.  it seems easy, but refactoring the test inputs are     soul-destroying.

**How can I manage the test stub and How can I overcome the huge input set ?**

Regards.

Comment: Have you thought about ways to automatically generate this input?

Comment: Maybe storing in a file with pipe seperated or json. I need  suggestions to manage them easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you have only two options: make less attributes relevant or learn to easily set-up tests with large number of attributes.

**less attributes**: refactor. and no one will give you much more detailed help because we don't know your business. try to find smaller groups of attributes that control some logic and test that logic using only those attributes.

**easy test set-up**: you can use customer builders. by default they create customer with some standard/most common settings and you tune the result however you want like

```
customer = makeCustomer().withActiveStatus(false).withDebit(3000).build()
```

Then, when new attribute appears you just have to change `makeCustomer()` in one place.

you can also use parameterized tests to define a test case as a one liner or load data from spreadsheet which may be easier to maintain.

Often when new attribute appears it's not that it changes everything completely. usually it just adds new behaviour in one spot when that attribute is non-standard. therefore usually it's just adding the default attribute to the builder and a few tests that override that attribute

another way to make tests easy is to do property testing (QuickCheck family) although not always it's easy to use it in business logic

Answer (score 1):

Use mocked customer. Setup only attributes that relevant for rule that you want test.

Comment: It will works but, It's not a real test. In my project, almost all attributes are setted.

Comment: What is "real test"? Such tests will check that your implementations are correct? If yes what else you need?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers, your best bet is to refactor those huge classes towards more fine-grained classes with a single responsibility, but in order to get your legacy code under test it might be worth looking into the test data [builder](http://natpryce.com/articles/000714.html) pattern.

In essence, test data builders provide an abstraction that hides away object construction. For example, they can provide default values for all constructor arguments, allowing you to specify the relevant ones in each of your tests (often through a fluent API which make your tests very readable).

```
new AddressBuilder()
    .withName("Sherlock Holmes")
    .withStreet("221b Baker Street")
    .withCity("London")
    .withPostCode("NW1", "3RX")
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

> In short, you have to create 4500 (90 x 50) attributes for a reliable
>   test.

No, you don't.  You're not thinking about this right.  You might need 4500 attributes for an *exhaustive* test, but not for a reliable test.

Mocking is an entirely legitimate and "real" - you're word - means of testing, and it's the appropriate answer here.

Comment: I'am wrong about this. I improved my question. Still need suggestions how to manage this huge input set. This is a sample, I have many objects like this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to make your code and tests more manageable.

> customer class has 58 attributes and it's related to address, marsaccounts and etc.

That's too many attributes for a single class.  You should try to refactor the class and break it up into many classes.  You mention addresses, if you have many attributes related to different fields of an address, you should refactor those out into an `Address` object.  Finding other similar related fields and pulling them out into their own objects will really help reduce the number of inputs and make it easier to mock in tests.

> Preparing the test inputs are painful and annoying. Imagine, 2 columns added to Customer object and they store critical values. it seems easy, but refactoring the test inputs are soul-destroying.

I would suggest making a Customer **TestDouble** for tests.  By default, this TestDouble will be initialized to have all 58+ attributes set to valid values.  The TestDouble will also have setters for all these values so they can be changed for each tests.

This way your test code doesn't duplicate setting all the irrelevant fields and makes the test more intent revealing.

For example:

```
@Test
public void invalidAccountIdShouldThrowBusinessRuleException(){

     CustomerTestDouble cust = new CustomerTestDouble();
     //only set what matters for this test
     cust.setMarsaccount( -1);

     BusinessRuleValidator validator = ...
     //wrap with whatever you do to check that validator throws Exception
     validator.validate(cust);
```

}

This is very clear that the exception will be thrown because the account id is `-1` there's no other clutter.

And if you have to add new fields to `Customer` later, (or refactor it to use new objects) most of your test code is unchanged.  Only the CustomerTestDouble and any directly affected tests need to be changed.

Comment: Cool. Is there any framework to manage data on files or etc. ?